# Website not detecting a shape I created on SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, sass, responsive-design

I am following a web development tutorial to create a landing page. I'm using a combination of CSS, HTML, and JS. My site will not detect a navigation bar that I have attempted to draw with SCSS. It's meant to be dark blue and sit on the top right. Below is the code for the project this far.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Easybank landing page</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <header class="header">
    <nav class="flex flex-jc-sb">
      <a href="/" class="header__logo">
        <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Easybank" />
      </a>

      <a href="#" class="header__menu">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div>

  <script src="/app/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.scss

```
@import "variables";
@import "globals";
@import "header";
```

_globals.scss

```
hmtl {
    font-size: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Public Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

/// Flexbox
.flex {
    display: flex;

    &-jc-sb {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &-jc-c {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    &-ai-c {
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

_headers.scss

```
.header {
    nav {
        padding: 24px;
    }

    &__menu { // Mobile Menu

      > span {
          display: block;
          width: 26px;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: $darkBlue;

          &:not(:last-child){
              margin-bottom: 3px;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want, what did you do, and what you get, as far as I understand you are trying to implement a Hamburger menu button for mobile view, is it correct? could you mention what is the current output exactly? are you sure that the variable is declared and imported correctly? could you debug using devTools to see what styles are added correctly and what are not?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add a menu button for a mobile view. It's supposed to have the three lines of a drop-down menu on the top right. None are appearing.